# sub query within linq select statement

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I want to get a list of student details and their attended hours using LINQ query in Entity Framework.

I am using the following query to bind a list of students details and the total hours attended  by them .

```
var students = (from pa in db.tblstudents
                select new studentModel
                {
                    Name = pa.Name,
                    StudentID = pa.ID,
                    RollNO = pa.rollNO,
                    Department = pa.Department,
                    Phone = pa.Phone,
                    Address = pa.Address,
                    TotalHours = (from time in tblhours 
                                  where time.studentID = pa.ID 
                                  select time.hours).Sum()
                }).Distinct().AsQueryable().ToList();

my studentModel looks like below:- 
public class StudentModel 
{ public string Name { get; set; } 
public int StudentID { get; set; }
 public string RollNO{ get; set; } 
public string DepartMent{ get; set; }
 public long Phone{ get; set; }
 public string Address{ get; set; }
 public string Address2{ get; set; }
 public decimal TotalHours{ get; set; }
 }
```

tblhours and tblstudent are related by studentid  and if i want to get hours attended by all students within the particular timeperiod how can i do that?

I get the error as "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities" when i try the above query

I think I am going wrong when I was selecting total hours using a subquery...

Comment: Your subquery shouldn't cause any problem. Maybe the `studentModel` class does. Could you share the code of this class. At least, the signature of the constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have an empty constructor in the `StudentModel` class

BTW, if you set up the relationship properly you should be able to do this as well

```
TotalHours = pa.tblhours.Sum(time=>time.hours)
```

Comment: tblhours and tblstudent are related by studentid  and if i want to get hours attended by each student within the particular timeperiod how can i do that?